# HackerEarth: How to read from STDIN and write to STDOUT?

Tags: javascript, stdout, stdin

Is anybody here who solves problems on HackerEarth? I am confused with the way they supply the input data.

I have been using Leetcode to date to solve problems and I am pretty happy with them but unfortunately, some people prefer HackerEarth to host coding challenges and I have issues trying to read the input test case properly.

Take this for example https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/ternary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/small-factorials/submissions/

I did my research and found their "solution guide" which has the wrong info: https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/solution-guide/

**How would I read the individual lines and output the results in JS (Node v10) judge?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Just logged into and looked it up [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/ternary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/small-factorials/activity/).
- Seems to be similar to HackerRank which I'm not fond of. (LeetCode's UI is fun and much easier to use.)
- On LeetCode, we don't have to print things out, here it seems we have to print the output (for instance in JavaScript we would use `console.log` not to mention printing inside methods is generally a bad practice coding).

This solution (copied from one of those activities) seems to be passing based on which you can figure things out:

```
/*
// Sample code to perform I/O:

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;                               // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});

function main(input) {
    process.stdout.write("Hi, " + input + ".\n");       // Writing output to STDOUT
}

// Warning: Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data to output will cause the test cases to fail
*/

// Write your code here


process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;
});
process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});
function main(input) {
    input = input.split('\n');
    input.shift();
    input.forEach(n => {
        n = parseInt(n);
        let fact = BigInt(1);
        while(n){
            fact = BigInt(fact) * BigInt(n);
            n--;
        }
        console.log(String(fact).replace('n',''));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Emma. This helps.

I never got to use BigInt till date in my JS journey, so I probably have to research for the same.

Comment: thanks for posting, the HERE link looks like its broken but this helps so much! you are the real mvp.

Answer (score 2):

in accessing inputs HackerEarth bit different compare to leetcode and Hacker Rank here you will have to extract inputs from standard input (STDIN) by line number you can find more details [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/tutorial/)

for example, if the format of the input given as below
***Input format:***
***First line contains integer N.

Second line contains string S.***

then you will split the STDIN by new line("\n") and access each input line-wise

below is a sample of how would you access inputs in JavaScript

```
var input1 = 0;
var input2 = "";
var stdin_input = ""
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    // Reading input from STDIN
    stdin_input += input;  
    input1 = stdin_input.split("\n")[0] 
    input2 = stdin_input.split("\n")[1]

    console.log("input1 = ", input1)
    console.log("input2 = ", input2)
                       
                             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***1- First step -->*** **Find the first occurrence of a number** using **Regex \d+** (No need to add the global flag as the problem stated that the first line always contains a number, thus we are looking for the first number). **The + flag is to always match more than one occurrence of a digit** like 2,12,21,234, and so on.

***2-Second Step -->*** **Cast the matched string to a number** to **multiply it by two (double it)**, then **cast it back to a string** and **make the replacement** using the regex replace methods.
More about the method can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;                             
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});

function main(input) {
    const regex = /(\d+)/g;
    let expr = input.replace(regex,(match) => {
        return String(Number(match) * 2);
    });
    process.stdout.write(expr);    
}
```

Comment: Please add some description for  your answer

Comment: Description added!